# I want to get load signature for doing current analysis on my cells with maximum possible data rate

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, embedded-linux

For doing this, I am using a current sensor that gives me current data(ADC conversion time-532 μs) in continuous conversion mode over I2C(400kHz) and I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero-W to store this data locally.  I want to connect the maximum number of sensors on one RPI Zero-W, using bit-banging on different RPI pins, I want to know what is the best method to do fetch data over I2C and store it when there are n current sensors for n cells.

I want to store the data as a separate CSV file for each cell. So, my question is focussed more towards optimizing the code in such a way that I get the maximum number of data points per second onto RPI and once it's on RPI, store it in a CSV file.

For each cell:
1. Get data on the Current Sensor(ADC conversion time)

2. Send the data over I2C (some microseconds to get the data on our RPI)
3. Store the fetched data in a CSV file

Comment: I think, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ is the right place to resolve your query.

Comment: I want to store the data as a separate CSV file for each cell. So, my question is focussed more towards optimizing the code in such a way that I get the maximum number of data points per second onto RPI and once its on RPI, store it in a CSV file.

Comment: You have just edited the Question, before that It doesn't seems to be more on the programming side.

Comment: You seem to be asking for how to optimize the code, yet you provide neither any code nor any description of how you have currently designed the system.  If you're looking for an overall "how do I start to design the system", that is too broad for this site.  You may have better luck at softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, however you'd still have to provide significantly more detail.

Comment: Why would you bit-bang it when RPi has an I2C interface?  I2C supports multiple devices on a single bus.  532us sounds suspiciously high for conversion time; what device are you using?  An ADC121C021 for example has a conversion time of 1us and can achieve 22Ksps on a 400Hz bus, so in your 532us you could read the conversion from perhaps 11 separate devices on a single bus.  Except of course Raspbian is not an RTOS, so you might expect some variation - to be honest it is a poor choice for the application because of that unless the ADC samples at a constant rate and buffers samples?